# Split image into blocks in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I want to split image into blocks matlab. For example, I have a matrix of 1000x651. I took the average of the red colors in this matrix and I wanted to print it out if the color is smaller than average. But I want to make a 32x32 matrix and I want to take red color average one by one on the matrixes. So, I want to check all 32x32 matrixes if the average of the matrix is less than the overall average, I will get the screen output. How can I do it?

```
img = imread('redcolor.jpg'); 
P = im2double(img);
G = P(:,:,2); 
a = min(min(G)); 
b = max(max(G)); 
c = mean(mean(G)); 
count = 0; 
for i = 1:1000 
    for j = 1:651
        if G(j,i) <= 0.8541
            fprintf( 'Red Color. \n') 
            count = count + 1;
        end
    end
end
fprintf('%d', count);
```

Comment: Would you please type the code here (as text) rather than posting it as an image? Thanks

Comment: I wanted write but I always take error.

Comment: Your image does not dividable by 32. What do you want to do with the margins?

Answer (score 0):

```
for i=1:32:size(image,1) - 32
    for j=1:32:size(image,2) - 32
         imagePart = image(i:i+31,j:j+31)
         %check whatever you want
    end
end
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out. I tested with a `rand` matrix as I don't have the real image. You should check that the image size is a multiple of 32x32 blocks or you may need to pad with zeros.

```
img = imread('redcolor.jpg'); 
P = im2double(img);
G = P(:,:,2); 
a = min(G(:)); 
b = max(G(:)); 
c = mean(G(:)); 
for i = 1:32:size(G,1) - 32
    for j = 1:32:size(G,2) - 32
         block = G(i:i+31, j:j+31);
         count = sum(block <= 0.8541);
         fprintf('%d\n', count);        
    end
end
```